# Best place to put onSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to add a setting to my app. I have added the new setting but I am not sure where to put `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. I put it in the activity and added a `Log.d()`, but the `Log.d()` is never triggered. Any ideas?

Comment: It will depend where you are updating your `SharedPreferences`. If they are being updated within the same `Activity` that implements the listener then it should work. If the `Activity` that implements the listener isn't currently running or if it is 'hidden' (paused/stopped etc) then it won't. If this has to work across `Activities` or `Services` etc then it would be better to extend the `Application` class and have it implement the listener.

Answer (score 3):

The best place according to [Android Settings doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Listening) would be:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
            .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

And you should store the listener in a field variable (or use the Activity object itself - as in the above source code), so that it does not get garbage collected.

I.e. an anonymous class object can't be used as `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. For example, in the parent activity that hosts your PreferenceFragment, a method such as initSharedPrefsListener() can be called in onCreate. This method would assign a 'new onSharedPreferenceChangeListener()' to a member variable, mListener. The register/unregister methods are called as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your listener by invoking [`setOnPreferenceChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html#setOnPreferenceChangeListener%28android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener%29). I'm going to assume that you have an Activity class that extends [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html). If so, that is the best place for your listener. You'd write something like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Load the preferences from an XML resource
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    Preference myPreference = findPreference("my_pref");
    myPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

Comment: The question was for `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` - also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604536/android-where-should-a-onsharedpreferencechangelistener-be-defined-registered)